# Use class as interface that can be passed into function

Tags: typescript

I am looking to be able to create a "factory" that allows me to pass in a class.

```
class Dolphin {};
class Seal {};

const returnsFunctionThatReturn = (c) => {
  return (): c => {};
}


returnsFunctionThatReturn(Dolphin)(); // should be a dolphin
returnsFunctionThatReturn(Seal)(); // should be a seal
```

Is something like this possible in TS?

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```
const returnsFunctionThatReturn = <T> (c: new () => T) => {
  return (): T => new c();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not, it is possible. However, you can only access public static variable and functions of those classes. Otherwise, you have to construct them before input them to a function.